# Disable eslint (typescript context) for a line when running eslint not working

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am struggling to disable a rule for one line of code.

I have this line of code:

```
public limit: number = 500
```

And my `eslint --fix` removes the type as it can be inferred. The problem is that class-validators requires that type so it knows what type to convert the string that is passed in.

I thus want to disable this "fix" for that line.

Right now I have:

```
  /* eslint-disable  @typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types */
  /* eslint-disable   */
  public limit: number = 500 // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types
  /* eslint-enable  @typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types */
```

And when the `estlint --fix` runs it still removes the type.

Apparently nestjs and class-validator should work without the type - that might only apply to the latest version of nestjs which I am not on.

The bottom line however is that eslint disable rules does not work for me.

Comment: Please give a [mre] - have you [disabled inline configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/rules#disabling-inline-comments), for example?

Comment: I removed your "_I have tried everything_" because it can't possibly be taken literally, and doesn't (by itself) provide any useful information to understand your problem or provide an answer (imho).

Comment: When you run `eslint` without `--fix`, what error/warning does it show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the responses I got egged me on to try harder and this is what I now know, perhaps it will help someone.

Consider that my field I'm wanting to change eslint rules for has decorators (and I assumed these would be irrelevant).

This works:

```
  /* eslint-disable */
  @IsInt({ message: 'Limit is provided but it is not a valid integer' })
  @IsOptional()
  // number type is _required_ for implicit conversion to work
  public limit: number = 500
  /* eslint-enable */
```

This, does *not* work... (notice how the disable comment is moved)

```
  @IsInt({ message: 'Limit is provided but it is not a valid integer' })
  @IsOptional()
  /* eslint-disable */
  // number type is _required_ for implicit conversion to work
  public limit: number = 500
  /* eslint-enable */
```

So the decorators do make a difference. It is significant where the disable rule appears.